# Connect webapp to hybrid connection

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-hybrid-connections

I have a webapp in one resource group, and a hybrid connection in another resource group. How can I connect this webapp that is in one RG to the Hybrid connection that is in another?

The command to connect to HC looks like this:

```
az webapp hybrid-connection add -g MyResourceGroup -n MyWebapp --namespace [HybridConnectionNamespace] --hybrid-connection [HybridConnectionName] -s [slot]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no resource group related limit in this case, just use the command as the sample you mentioned.

My web app and hybrid connection locate in different resource group with different region, it work fine.

```
az webapp hybrid-connection add -g '<webapp-group>' -n '<webapp-name>' --namespace '<relay-name>' --hybrid-connection '<connection-name>'
```

[image]

---

**Tip:**

If you got the error like below, please make sure you have set the `User Metadata` for the hybrid connection.

[image]

In my sample, `testhost` is the `Endpoint Host`, `123` is the `Endpoint Port`.

```
[{"key":"endpoint","value":"testhost:123"}]
```

[image]